# How to use result returned from before or background scenarios in cucumber java testing?

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have two scenarios named "X" and "Y" ( many others)
Before testing scenario "Y", I need to run Scenario "X" and return the results from scenario "X" to scenario "Y". How should I do that ?

I have tried 2 options
1: I have created background scenario for X but I am not able to return result from that background scenario X to scenario Y.
2: I have also tried using before hook up annotation.

(PS: I know while testing all test-cases should be independent of each other)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way is to place both steps in the same class then use class instance variables.

```
public class SomeSteps {
  private List<String> betweenStepsList;

  @When("^I initialize a list in one step$") 
  public void iInitializeAListInOneStep() {
    betweenStepsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Peter","Piper","picked","a","peck","of","pickled","peppers"));
  }

  @Then("^I can access that list in a following step$") 
  public void iCanAccessThatListInAFollowingStep() {
    System.out.println("Elements are:" + betweenStepsList);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
You did say two scenarios. When I face this issue I always find a way to combine the scenarios into one.

You could write the intermediate results to a file in the first scenario and then read them in the second.  I never bother to do this myself but there are lots of tutorials on how to read and write files. Here is [one](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html) for Java. Ruby or Python (you didn't specify) examples for writing then reading a file are also easily available.

Parallel execution is fine as long as both scenarios are in the same feature file.

Comment: This won't work. Steps instance classes are recreated between each scenario. It will however work when using the first step in a background scenario.

Comment: Right you are. Combing scenarios into one is so ingrained in my approach that I failed to state it.